# cutting particular value in a text file and store it in a variable

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text by name setting.conf, the content of the text goes like this

```
area1mood1="${Script_3}+IR_D01+AC_OFF_   ${Script_2}+CR_D601+C1_OPN ${Script_1}+SR_D301+LT_1ON ${Script_1}+SR_D301+LT_2TG ${Script_1}+       SR_D301+LT_3ON ${Script_1}+SD_D405+DM_1L0 ${Script_1}+SD_D405+DM_2L0 ${Script_1}+SD_D405+DM_3LC"
```

I have to access the values

```
IR_D01+AC_OFF_
CR_D601+C1_OPN
SR_D301+LT_1ON
SR_D301+LT_2TG
SR_D301+LT_3ON
SD_D405+DM_1L0
SD_D405+DM_2L0
SD_D405+DM_3LC
```

In the above string, i used `cut -d' ' -f1 -s` but i get the entire string between spaces. And how to cut till it goes to end of line and to store these values in a variable. I want all those values to be stored in variable.Can anyone help. I am new to bash scripting.

Comment: `${Script_[0-9]}` will be expanded, the values of those variable could effect the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have GNU grep:

```
grep -oP '(?<=}\+)[^\s"]+' <<'END'
area1mood1="${Script_3}+IR_D01+AC_OFF_   ${Script_2}+CR_D601+C1_OPN ${Script_1}+SR_D301+LT_1ON ${Script_1}+SR_D301+LT_2TG ${Script_1}+       SR_D301+LT_3ON ${Script_1}+SD_D405+DM_1L0 ${Script_1}+SD_D405+DM_2L0 ${Script_1}+SD_D405+DM_3LC"
END
```

```
IR_D01+AC_OFF_
CR_D601+C1_OPN
SR_D301+LT_1ON
SR_D301+LT_2TG
SD_D405+DM_1L0
SD_D405+DM_2L0
SD_D405+DM_3LC
```

That misses "SR_D301+LT_3ON" because of the whitespace before it -- you can't have a variable length look-behind. This works though:

```
perl -nle 'print for /\}\+\s*([^\s"]+)/g' <<'END'
area1mood1="${Script_3}+IR_D01+AC_OFF_   ${Script_2}+CR_D601+C1_OPN ${Script_1}+SR_D301+LT_1ON ${Script_1}+SR_D301+LT_2TG ${Script_1}+       SR_D301+LT_3ON ${Script_1}+SD_D405+DM_1L0 ${Script_1}+SD_D405+DM_2L0 ${Script_1}+SD_D405+DM_3LC"
END
```

```
IR_D01+AC_OFF_
CR_D601+C1_OPN
SR_D301+LT_1ON
SR_D301+LT_2TG
SR_D301+LT_3ON
SD_D405+DM_1L0
SD_D405+DM_2L0
SD_D405+DM_3LC
```